# How to save changes in html file while surfing?

Tags: html, save

I have a movie list in html file. Every movie has a checkbox near it. I want to check this checkboxes when i looking list in IE, Chrome, Firefox etc. And then save it. When i open list again checkboxes must be checked. I can do it with codes in notepad. But i want to do it with IE, Chrome, Firefox etc. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Usual way is by using cookies. But it is browser specific, cookies only saved on the browser which u apply the changes.

There are a few ways u can implement cookies using just javascript. Easiest way is to use jquery:
[Jquery Cookie Plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js)

I don't know how much you know about cookies, just in case u don't:
[What is Cookie?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If i use "Jquery Cookie Plugin" will the checkboxes checked when i open list another computer or browser? I want to check the checkboxes permanently